# Fastest way to check if set exists in database set

Tags: mysql, performance

Say I have a database with millions of urls with millions more to come. I need a fast way of checking if a batch of urls exist in the database. At the moment I have this:

```
foreach($urls as $url) {
  $this->db->or_where('url', $url->url);
}
```

Which produces queries like this:

```
WHERE url = 'foo' OR url = 'bar' OR ...
```

Are there faster ways to check if sets of data exist in a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someting like:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table1 url = 'foo' OR url = 'bar' OR ...
)
```