# using case when exists to check if records are present in the db

Tags: java, sql, oracle, prepared-statement

Which query will be faster

> SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE condition ) 
>                 THEN 'Y' 
>                 ELSE 'N' 
>            END FROM DUAL

or

> SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE condition

for both of them I am setting the *fetchSize* as 1.

But, I am wondering if I use the second query, I will just need to check *if ( rs.next() )*, whereas for the first query, I need to check an additional condition *rs.getString(1).equals("Y")*. At the same time I am wondering *if using when exists in the sql, somehow makes the query faster*?

I have checked other questions [The fastest way to check if some records in a database table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131168/the-fastest-way-to-check-if-some-records-in-a-database-table) and [Fastest way to check if set exists in database set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652284/fastest-way-to-check-if-set-exists-in-database-set), they talk about using exists. So, just wondering if I should use exists, and *if I need to use it to make the query faster, how does it make the query faster?*

Answer (score 1):

regarding you could get 'no_data_found' or 'to_many_rows' that leads to reading dictionary to get error code and so on and so forth using the statement 'SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE condition' the first way will be faster

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE condition
```

**If the resulset returns no rows it means the condition was not met, else condition was met.**

It's better, cleaner, shorter, faster.

Comment: Your answer is correct only in case of there is 1 (not more and no less) records with the condition else it is incorrect and slower. In my answer I explained why but if you don't believe - just make test case with 3 types of results: the lion's share is data which satisfies the condition and there is only 1 record, the best part doesn't satisfy the condition, there are a lot of cases where more than one record satisfy the condition.